# How to exclude .pdb files in CI/CD pipeline Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I have created a CI/CD pipeline for several different websites, and for few web applications. However, when I am releasing those website to their physical path, a new group of files with the ".pdb" extension are being generated. How could I somehow disable this feature in my build or release pipeline?

Thank you.

Comment: just compile it in `release` mode and not in `debug`

Comment: I am already compiling it in a release mode. That did not help.

Answer (score 0):

> How to exclude .pdb files in CI/CD pipeline Azure DevOps

You could try to edit the `pubxml` file (under `Properties` / `PublishProfiles` of your web project).

Then add `bin\**\*.pdb` (`**` is there to mean any hierarchy even none between `bin` and your `pdb` files) to the node `ExcludeFilesFromDeployment`.

The `pubxml` thus look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>bin\**\*.pdb</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following PowerShell Script in the Release Pipeline.

```
Write-Host "Delete PDB Files from the Artifact"

Get-ChildItem $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/PROJECT-PATH/drop/bin/*.pdb | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName }

Write-Host "PDB Files removed form the Artifact"
```